# Strictly singular operators

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T$ be a compact operator from a Banach space $X$ to a Banach space $Y$. I'm trying to prove that $T$ is a strictly singular. If $Z$ is a subspace of $X$, it's easy to see that, if $Z$ is closed and $T|_Z:Z\to T(Z)$ is a isomorfism, then $T(B_Z)$ is closed in $\overline{T(B_X)}$, which proves that $B_Z$ is compact and, hence, $Z$ is finite dimensional. Now, how to proceed for the case in which $Z$ is not closed in $X$?

Comment: I know that this is an old post. But I got a quick question here. What does $B_Z$ represent here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Isomorphism" in this case is a bounded linear operator with a bounded inverse.  If $T$ is an isomorphism on $Z$, show that it and its inverse extend by continuity to give an isomorphism on $\overline{Z}$.